# MessageBodyWriter most suitable Variant

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

The `MessageBodyWriter.writeTo` method includes `MediaType mediaType` and `MultivaluedMap<String,Object> httpHeaders`.

`mediaType` is supposed to be the most appropiate output format, but how is it being selected when multiple `Accept` header values are included (i.e. `application/xml, q=0.5; application/json, q=0.9`).

Besides, how is the best variant selected (language, etc.)? Using `Request.selectVariant()` is possible to do it automatically, but I haven't found how to do so within the `MessageBodyWriter`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Besides, how is the best variant selected (language, etc.)?

That really depends on the implementation.

> but I haven't found how to do so within the MessageBodyWriter

Because `MessageBodyWriter.writeTo` doesn't really care about selecting the best variant. After checking a few implementations, like [StringProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.2/com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/StringProvider.java#StringProvider.writeTo%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.reflect.Type%2Cjava.lang.annotation.Annotation[]%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29), [SerializableProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.2.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/SerializableProvider.java#SerializableProvider.writeTo%28java.io.Serializable%2Cjava.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.reflect.Type%2Cjava.lang.annotation.Annotation[]%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29) or [FormMultivaluedMapProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.9.1/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/AbstractFormProvider.java#AbstractFormProvider.writeTo%28javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap%2Cjavax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%2Cjava.io.OutputStream%29) it seems clear that they just take the input, and write it to the output stream in their respecitve formats: as a string, as a serialized object or as a form encoded string. They only use `mediaType` for such minor details as the character encoding they should use.

Therefore the decision about the most appropriate output format has to be decided before choosing the used `MessageBodyWriter` implementation as e.g. a `StringProvider` will always only output the string, and won't care if it's a JSON string or and XML string or something else.